# Error checking for NULL in VBScript, getting "Object Required"

Tags: vbscript, null, asp-classic, nullreferenceexception

I have the following VBScript in a Classic ASP page:

```
function getMagicLink(fromWhere, provider)
    dim url 
    url = "magic.asp?fromwhere=" & fromWhere
    If Not provider is Nothing Then ' Error occurs here
        url = url & "&provider=" & provider 
    End if
    getMagicLink = "<a target='_blank' href='" & url & "'>" & number & "</a>"
end function
```

I keep getting an "Object Required" error messager on the line that says `If Not provider Is Nothing Then`.

Either the value is NULL, or it's not NULL, so why am I getting this error?

**Edit:** When I invoke the object, I pass in either NULL, or I pass in a string.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From your code, it looks like `provider` is a variant or some other variable, and not an object.

`Is Nothing` is for objects only, yet later you say it's a value that should either be NULL or NOT NULL, which would be handled by `IsNull`.

Try using:

```
If Not IsNull(provider) Then 
    url = url & "&provider=" & provider 
End if
```

Alternately, if that doesn't work, try:

```
If provider <> "" Then 
    url = url & "&provider=" & provider 
End if
```

Comment: I tried using `If Not IsNull(provider) Then`, but then the page raises an exception on `url = url & "&provider=" & provider` line.  The error says, "Object variable not set".

Comment: That's a head-scratcher.  Are you passing in `vbNull` to `provider`, or something else?

Comment: I was always taught `Nothing` is for objects only, try passing in `vbNull` instead.  `Nothing` <> `Null` in VBScript.

Comment: Use `Null`, not `vbNull`. `vbNull` is a constant that is used with the [`VarType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3kfz157h%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function.

Answer (score 25):

I see lots of confusion in the comments. `Null`, `IsNull()` and `vbNull` are mainly used for database handling and normally not used in VBScript. If it is not explicitly stated in the documentation of the calling object/data, do not use it.

To test if a variable is uninitialized, use `IsEmpty()`. To test if a variable is uninitialized or contains `""`, test on `""` or `Empty`. To test if a variable is an object, use `IsObject` and to see if this object has no reference test on `Is Nothing`.

In your case, you first want to test if the variable is an object, and then see if that variable is `Nothing`, because if it isn't an object, you get the "Object Required" error when you test on `Nothing`.

snippet to mix and match in your code:

```
If IsObject(provider) Then
    If Not provider Is Nothing Then
        ' Code to handle a NOT empty object / valid reference
    Else
        ' Code to handle an empty object / null reference
    End If
Else
    If IsEmpty(provider) Then
        ' Code to handle a not initialized variable or a variable explicitly set to empty
    ElseIf provider = "" Then
        ' Code to handle an empty variable (but initialized and set to "")
    Else
        ' Code to handle handle a filled variable
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I will just add a blank ("") to the end of the variable and do the comparison.  Something like below should work even when that variable is null.  You can also trim the variable just in case of spaces.

```
If provider & "" <> "" Then 
    url = url & "&provider=" & provider 
End if
```