# Error 424 with C++ ATL OleAutomation

Tags: c++, vba, com, atl

I am unexpectedly receiving an Error 424 from an object that works.

I have a number of OleAutomation classes written in C++ using ATL.

I can instantiate them with either early or late binding.
I can call methods and properties on them and obtain expected results.

However I receive Error 424 if I test whether they are null.

Are there any suggestions as to the problem ?

Excel VBA code that triggers error:

```
Sub ObjectTest()
    Dim o As About

    Set o = New About

    ' this works - prints 1.4
    Debug.Print "Version ", o.Version

    ' generates Error 424 
    Debug.Print "About ", o Is Null
End Sub
```

The IDL

```
[
     object,
     oleautomation,
     uuid(...),
     dual,
     nonextensible,
     pointer_default(unique),
     public
]
interface IAbout : IDispatch
{
     ...
     [propget, id(3), helpstring("Library version string")]
     HRESULT Version([out, retval] BSTR* pResult);
     ...
};


[
    uuid(...)       
]
coclass About
{
    [default] interface IAbout;
};
```

The registration

```
HKCR
{
    MyLibrary.About.1 = s 'About MyLibrary'
    {
        CLSID = s '{...}'
    }
    MyLibrary.About = s 'About MyLibrary'
    {
        CLSID = s '{...}'
        CurVer = s 'MyLibrary.About.1'
    }
    NoRemove CLSID
    {
        ForceRemove {...} = s 'Class About'
        {
            ProgID = s 'MyLibrary.About.1'
            VersionIndependentProgID = s 'MyLibrary.About'
            ForceRemove Programmable
            InprocServer32 = s '%MODULE%'
            {
                val ThreadingModel = s 'Apartment'
            }
            TypeLib = s '{...}'
            Version = s '1.0'
        }
    }
}
```

And the class

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CAbout :
    public ATL::CComObjectRootEx<ATL::CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public ATL::CComCoClass<CAbout, &CLSID_About>,
    public ATL::ISupportErrorInfoImpl<&CLSID_About>,
    public ATL::IDispatchImpl<IAbout, &IID_IAbout, &LIBID_MyLibrary, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>
{
public:
    CAbout()
    {
    }

DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_ABOUT)

DECLARE_NOT_AGGREGATABLE(CAbout)

BEGIN_COM_MAP(CAbout)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IAbout)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(ISupportErrorInfo)
END_COM_MAP()



    DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()

    HRESULT FinalConstruct()
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

    void FinalRelease()
    {
    }

public:

    ...
    STDMETHOD(get_Version)( /* [out, retval] */ BSTR* pResult );
    ...

};

OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO(__uuidof(About), CAbout)
```

Any help with why it generates error 424 for test "is null"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error checking for NULL in VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507526/error-checking-for-null-in-vbscript)

Comment: It is just bad syntax, Null is not the same thing as Nothing.  Put `Option Strict On` at the top of the source code file.

Comment: I love that you expect to get an error code if it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is ["Object Required"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwbk3483%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and is solely related to VBA side (unrelated to C++ and ATL). You should not test for `Null`ness this way, since this is what is generating the error.

See answer on [Error checking for NULL in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507526/error-checking-for-null-in-vbscript) for Null testing options you actually have.