# ASP Classic check for database NULL value in Recordset

Tags: asp-classic, null, adodb

I'm getting an ADODB Recordset and I need to check the value of a nullable column in ASP Classic.  How can I tell whether it's null?  AFAIK IsDBNull doesn't exist in ASP Classic, and all the Null testers ask whether the object is null, not its value.

E.g., I have Recordset `RS` that contains a column `RS("myCol")`.  In the database, myCol is a nullable bit, so values can be `{0, 1, NULL}`.

How can I test `RS("myCol") = NULL`?  It appears that if I literally run that comparison it will only tell me whether the object RS("myCol") is Null, not whether the value of the field requested is "database" null.

Comment: `IsNull()` will not work because ADO Nulls are treated differently to Null values in VBScript. Just use `Len(RS("myCol") & "") > 0` to check for Null columns.

Comment: `IsNull` is the correct way for checking for the special value of `Variant/Null` which the database nulls are translated to. Concatenating nulls with a `""` in order to coerce them to an empty string, on the other hand, is a hack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, it should work if you are using MS SQL

```
IF IsNull(RS("myCol")) = False THEN
  IF RS("myCol") THEN
    Response.Write "myCol is TRUE"
  ELSE
    Response.Write "myCol is False"
  END IF
ELSE
  Response.Write "myCol is NULL"
END IF
```

or Try Using

```
IF RS("myCol")<>"" THEN
  IF RS("myCol") THEN
    Response.Write "myCol is TRUE"
  ELSE
    Response.Write "myCol is False"
  END IF
ELSE
  Response.Write "myCol is NULL"
END IF
```

Comment: Again, it won't for reasons [detailed above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38927714/asp-classic-check-for-database-null-value-in-recordset#comment65216465_38927714).

Comment: I don't why, but surprisingly it does work for me :)

Comment: Will depend on the provider being used.

Comment: `IsNull` is the correct way for checking for the special value of `Variant/Null` which the database nulls are translated to.

Answer (score 0):

For a database column `myCol` of type `nullable bit`, the following will be true of a Recordset `RS` containing that column:

- If the database value is 0, then `RS("myCol") = Empty = False = 0`
- If the database value is 1, then `RS("myCol") = True = 1`
- If the database value is Null, then `IsNull(RS("myCol")) = True = 1`.

Another solution:

- If the database value is 0 then `Len(RS("myCol")&"") = 5`
- If the database value is 1 then `Len(RS("myCol")&"") = 4`
- If the database value is Null then `Len(RS("myCol")&"") = 0`

Comment: Probably useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507526/error-checking-for-null-in-vbscript

Comment: `IsNull()` will not work because ADO Nulls are treated differently to Null values in VBScript. Just use `Len(RS("myCol") & "") > 0` to check for Null columns.

Comment: @Lankymart: Your solution wouldn't work because both `0` and `Null` would produce `Len = 0`.  I verified my answer by running in a real ASP classic website pulling from a real MS SQL database.  So it works in my environment.  Are you saying that it *shouldn't* work?  Or that it is *not guaranteed* to work in such an environment?

Comment: What are you on about? I was showing how to check for database nulls without receiving an error. Ofc it would be 0 that's the whole point of `> 0` check.

Comment: @Lankymart: The question is *how to detect and distinguish between the three values of a nullable bit*.  I.e., it's not enough to avoid an error when the value is Null.  I need to be able to distinguish in the ASP between a value of Null and a value of 0.

Comment: It can `0`, `1` or `Null` - `Len(RS("myCol") & "") > 0` deals with the null condition. So what's your point again?

Comment: @Lankymart - If the value is 0/False then `Len(RS("myCol") & "") = 0` also.  So `Len(RS("myCol") & "")` cannot distinguish between a value of Null and a value of zero for a database bit field.

Comment: What are you going on about? I'm so confused now your talking absolute rubbish `Len(0 & "")` is `1`, `Len(DBNullValue & "")` is `0`. It you have a value *(any value!!)* it will have a length greater then zero. I've used this approach for years and years so don't even try and justify your comments because you are plain wrong matey.

Comment: @Lankymart - I just tested your solution and found it works, so I added it to the answer.

Comment: I know it does. But why would a value of `1` have a length of `4`?? Whatever your testing your doing it wrong should be length of `1`. The **whole** answer is just wrong.

Comment: @Lankymart - Obviously because the server is choosing to interpret a bit value of 1 as "True" and 0 as "False."  Don't shoot the messenger.  These are the actual results on an actual system: IIS 6 or 7, MS SQL 2008 or 2012.

Comment: First right thing you've said, forgot we are talking about bits so they will be interpreted as a `Boolean`. But like I said earlier the approach works for **any** value *(except object references)*.

Comment: The third value on the second solution is for `Null` not `0`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Function A9000_Coalesce(SqlValue, ValueIfNull)

    If VarType(SqlValue) = vbNull Then 
        A9000_Coalesce = ValueIfNull
    Else
        A9000_Coalesce = SqlValue
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score -2):

In server side Javascript you have to test

```
if (RS("myCol").Value))
```

instead of

```
if (RS("myCol")))
```

so probably in VBScript you need to use

```
IF IsNull(RS("myCol").Value) THEN
```

to actually test for the value and not the object.

Comment: I don't know about JavaScript but the `ADODB.Recordset` object has a default property of `Value` on the `Fields` collection so `RS("myCol")` is equivalent to `RS("myCol").Value`.