# Apply existing VBS folder search to sub folders?

Tags: excel, vbscript, directory, subdirectory

I am using the following code to search a folder for a file name, open the file run an excel macro, save the file, and close. I would like to extend this to loop through sub folders and do the same. There should only be one layer of sub folders but multiple folders in that layer.

```
dir = "C:\Users\ntunstall\Desktop\test"

Sub RunMacroAndSaveAs(file, macro)
  Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open(file)
  app.Run wb2.Name & "!" & macro
  wb.SaveAs fso.BuildPath(file.ParentFolder, fso.GetBaseName(file) & ".xlsm"), 52
  wb.Close
End Sub

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
app.Visible       = False
app.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb2 = app.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ntunstall\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB")

For Each file In fso.GetFolder(dir).Files
  If InStr(file.Name, "OPS") > 0 Then
    RunMacroAndSaveAs file, "Main"
  ElseIf InStr(file.Name, "Event") > 0 Then
    RunMacroAndSaveAs file, "Events"
  End If
Next
wScript.Quit
app.Quit
```

How can I modify this code to search sub folders?

Solution:

```
dir = "C:\Users\ntunstall\Desktop\test"

Sub RunMacroAndSaveAs(file, macro)
  Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open(file)
  Set wb2 = app.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ntunstall\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB")
  app.Run wb2.Name & "!" & macro
  wb.SaveAs fso.BuildPath(file.ParentFolder, fso.GetBaseName(file) & ".xlsm"), 52
  wb.Close
End Sub

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
app.Visible = False

Dim path: path = "C:\Users\ntunstall\Desktop\test"
Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Call this to trigger the recursion.
Call TraverseFolders(fso.GetFolder(path))

Sub TraverseFolders(fldr)
  Dim f, sf
  ' do stuff with the files in fldr here, or ...
  For Each f In fldr.Files
    If InStr(f.Name, "OPS") > 0 Then
      Call RunMacroAndSaveAs(f, "Main")
    ElseIf InStr(f.Name, "Event") > 0 Then
      Call RunMacroAndSaveAs(f, "Events")
    End If
  Next
  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    Call TraverseFolders(sf)  '<- recurse here
  Next
  ' ... do stuff with the files in fldr here.
End Sub

wScript.Quit
app.Quit
```

Comment: Ideally, you want to [use a Recursive Function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14965606/692942) to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursively access subfolder files inside a folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950475/recursively-access-subfolder-files-inside-a-folder)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I had viewed that questions before posting mine and, honestly, I have no idea how to implement that. I am not a programmer; just try to do some small things to make my life easier. I have, unfortunately, exhausted my knowledge(I had to ask a question just to get the code above...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently [I'm not helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41187136/apply-existing-vbs-folder-search-to-sub-folders/41192464#comment69584111_41187947)...

```
Dim path: path = "C:\Users\ntunstall\Desktop\test"
Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Call this to trigger the recursion.
Call TraverseFolders(fso.GetFolder(path))

Sub TraverseFolders(fldr)
  Dim f, sf
  ' do stuff with the files in fldr here, or ...
  For Each f In fldr.Files
    If InStr(f.Name, "OPS") > 0 Then
      Call RunMacroAndSaveAs(f, "Main")
    ElseIf InStr(f.Name, "Event") > 0 Then
      Call RunMacroAndSaveAs(f, "Events")
    End If
  Next
  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    Call TraverseFolders(sf)  '<- recurse here
  Next

  ' ... do stuff with the files in fldr here.
End Sub
```

Taken from the method by [@ansgar-wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) - [A: Recursively access subfolder files inside a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14965606/692942) which I already flagged as a duplicate.

Have tested this using

```
WScript.Echo f.Name
```

in place of the `RunMacroAndSaveAs()` Sub Procedure if it is still erroring the issue lies there as this recursion works fine.

Comment: I appreciate the fact that beginners are helped at Stackoverflow

Answer (score -1):

Steps towards the solution:

1. Create the following method:

   ```
   Sub IterateFolder(dir, fso)
     For Each file In fso.GetFolder(dir).Files
       If InStr(file.Name, "OPS") > 0 Then
         RunMacroAndSaveAs file, "Main"
       ElseIf InStr(file.Name, "Event") > 0 Then
         RunMacroAndSaveAs file, "Events"
       End If
     Next
   End Sub`
   ```

and call it like this: `IterateFolder "C:\Users\ntunstall\Desktop\test", fso`

This will still do this for the first level, but do this as a first step and understand it.

2. Understand [fso.SubFolders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251693.aspx)
3. Apply the new knowledge:

   ```
   Sub IterateFolder(dir, fso)
     For Each file In fso.GetFolder(dir).Files
       If InStr(file.Name, "OPS") > 0 Then
         RunMacroAndSaveAs file, "Main"
       ElseIf InStr(file.Name, "Event") > 0 Then
         RunMacroAndSaveAs file, "Events"
       End If
     Next
     For Each sf In fso.SubFolders
       IterateFolder sf, fso
     Next
   End Sub
   ```

I do not work with VBScript, therefore I am not 100% sure if I'm right. If you have any problems with the solution, please ask.

EDIT:

As pointed out in the commenting section, `fso` is a variable which was out of scope in the `Sub`. I have edited my answer to make sure it is passed.

EDIT2:

Let's hope this is the coup de grace. I was mistaken in the way subfolders were iterated. Change this chunk:

```
For Each sf In fso.SubFolders
  IterateFolder sf, fso
Next
```

to this:

```
For Each sf In fso.GetFolder(dir).SubFolders
  IterateFolder sf, fso
Next
```

EDIT3:

We need to check SubFolders against null. According to this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507526/error-checking-for-null-in-vbscript), we should change this:

```
For Each sf In fso.GetFolder(dir).SubFolders
  IterateFolder sf, fso
Next
```

to this:

```
If Not IsNull(fso.GetFolder(dir).SubFolders) Then
  For Each sf In fso.GetFolder(dir).SubFolders
    IterateFolder sf, fso
  Next
End If
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130832/discussion-on-answer-by-lajos-arpad-apply-existing-vbs-folder-search-to-sub-fold).